# How to close Dialog box?

Tags: javascript, ribbon, modal-dialog, dialog-framework

I have Ribbon button that when it's clicked you get a dialog window open. On that window I have a button that I want to use to close the dialog window when clicked.

This is the code for the dialog

```
 HostWebDialog="TRUE"
 HostWebDialogWidth="480"
 HostWebDialogHeight="240">
```

and on the App.js file I have a click function

```
$("#Blue").click(function () {



});
```

I use Visual Studio 2013 and SharePoint online, I want to do it with javascipt

**EDIT**

Right answer

```
window.parent.postMessage('CloseCustomActionDialogRefresh', '*');
window.parent.postMessage('CloseCustomActionDialogNoRefresh', '*');
```

Comment: Please post an answer with your answer, do not add it as an edit to your question (it makes it impossible for future readers to find it with ease)

Comment: ok då vet jag hur jag ska göra

Answer (score 1):

So if `SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult, returnVal)` is not working you can try [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/richard_dizeregas_blog/archive/2013/03/10/leveraging-sharepoint-dialogs-in-apps-for-sharepoint.aspx):

> Closing the Dialog Autohosted and Provider-hosted Apps for SharePoint
>   are hosted outside of SharePoint, and as such can’t leverage typical
>   SharePoint scripts to close the dialog (ex:
>   SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose()).  Luckily, I have hunted
>   through many lines of core.js to find you the solution!  Similar to
>   resizing app parts (client web parts), we can use the HTML5
>   postMessage API to close the dialog from the app (and optionally
>   refresh the parent page).  This shouldn’t come as a surprise, since
>   the postMessage API was meant to provide cross-domain communication
>   and is used in other app scenarios.  CloseCustomActionDialogRefresh
>   and CloseCustomActionDialogNoRefresh are the two messages SharePoint
>   is “listening” for to close the dialog.  I wrapped these in a simple
>   function I can releverage across all my apps:

```
 function closeParentDialog(refresh) {
    var target = parent.postMessage ? parent : (parent.document.postMessage ? parent.document : undefined);
    if (refresh)
        target.postMessage('CloseCustomActionDialogRefresh', '*');
    else
        target.postMessage('CloseCustomActionDialogNoRefresh', '*');
}
```

Comment: Hi i find that post but did't get it to work :/

Comment: Here the same recommendation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220046(v=office.15).aspx.  window.parent.postMessage('CloseCustomActionDialogRefresh', '*');
window.parent.postMessage('CloseCustomActionDialogNoRefresh', '*');